# DataGridview is not Reloading/Refreshing after updating the data?

Tags: c#, winforms

guys it is not refreshing the datagridview when i close the form(Form1) rather its make record duplicate,I have two form by double click on gridview control goes to form1 where after updating the data it does not change the record on gridview i have to restart the program to check the changes  , i call Gridviewload(); method in  showstudentinfo function where by closing form1 its update the record as i watched in the tutorial don't know what the problem in my program.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private void DetailsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewLoad();
}

private void GridViewLoad()
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = GetDeatilsList();
}
private DataTable GetDeatilsList()
{
    string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetallRecords",con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
             SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             dt.Load(rdr);
        }
    }
   return dt;
}

private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowtoUpdate = dataGridView1.Rows.GetFirstRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
    int studentId = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[rowtoUpdate].Cells["ID"].Value);
    showstudentinfo(studentId, true);
}

private void showstudentinfo(int studentid, bool isupdate)
{
    Form1 sti = new Form1();
    sti.StudentID = studentid;
    sti.ISupdate = isupdate;
    sti.ShowDialog();
    GridViewLoad();
}
```

Comment: where are you actually binding the dataSource to the DataGrid..?

Comment: Global variables are evil

Comment: `dt.Load(rdr);` doesnt remove the last results or empty the datatable

Comment: @Plutonix after reading your comment i have changed my code to this still same problem
                      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    //SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    con.Close();

Comment: @MethodMan in GridViewLoad method i bind the datasource

Comment: you are assigning the DataSource.. but you need to call the Refresh method for the rows to show.. after this line `dataGridView1.DataSource = GetDeatilsList();` add the following 
`dataGridView1.Refresh();`

Comment: @Arslanjappa remove the global variable dt and declare it locally inside GetDeatilsList

Comment: You still arent doing anything to the datatable.  use a new one or clear the previous results.  That is a full reload **not** a refresh (pick up just the changes)

Comment: @Steve thanks for suggestion i made the datatable variable local and this solved my problem.